# Unable to iterate over stream inside use{} block

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data

I just want to print name of every user stored in database.

I am using this repository:

```
@Repository
interface User: JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>, PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("from User")
    fun findAllUsers(): Stream<User>
}
```

inside this Service:

```
@Service
class MyService(val user: User) {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    fun printNames() {
        log.info("here")
        user.findAllUsers().use { users ->
            users.map { it.firstName }
        }
    }
}
```

and it prints only *here* in console, but no name.

It seems like *map()* automatically closed the stream but I don`t know why and how to workaround it. When I put inside of use{} block only log.info(users.count()) it prints number of users stored in database. So there is a user I can print.

My question is, how can I print all names from the given stream?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use Stream with kotlin?

Comment: Apart from the lazy `map` that doesn't do anything, note that there are no print or log statements with the users here, how did you expect them to be printed?

Comment: It was just an example since I need to pass the user object to another function where is send to Kafka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin's `use` function is just a short-hand way of executing some code (your closure function) and then call `close` on the receiver (in this case the `Stream`) once done.

What you called `users` is actually the `Stream<User>`returned by your repository, so basically your code is just calling `users.map {...}`. Now, the `map` operator is an intermediate operator, and since Java streams are lazy, they won't actually do anything until you call a terminal operator (such as `.collect` or `.forEach`).

Assuming you want to print the user, try with:

```
user.findAllUsers().use {
    it.forEach { println(it.firstName) }
}
```

Full working example (without Spring data):

```
import java.util.stream.Stream

// simulate a repository
fun findAllUsers() = Stream.of("First", "Second", "Third")

fun printNames() {
    findAllUsers().use {
        it.forEach(::println)
    }
}

fun main() {
    printNames()
}
```

Prints:

```
First
Second
Third
```